# Jquery <input> tags not shown in the correct number

Tags: jquery

I have this problem in my website: if I click on the $("#new-comment") button, jquery shows an input tag where I can write a comment, then I press enter and the new comment is added. But I have this problem: if I want to insert another comment immediately after the last insertion (without uploading the page, if I press f5 this doesn't happen), when I click on the button, jquery shows two input tags, each one appended after the other. If after having added a second comment, I want to write a third one, jquery shows three tags and so on... I think that the problem is when I use the append function on the third line, but I don't know how to solve this. (NOTE: I have written this line $newReview.remove(): because otherwise, after the enter pressing, jquery showed me another input tag with the same text I have written immediately after the new comment; this is also a problem).

```js
function reviews(){
    $("#review_title").show();
    $("#reviews").show();
    $("#new-comment").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:'reviews/reviews_query.php',
        data: {show:true, title:$("#right_title").text()},     
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(json){
            var ris = JSON.parse(json);
            $("#reviews").html("<ul></ul>");
            for(var i=0; i<ris.length; i++){
                var name = "<span class='rev_name'>"+ ris[i].username + "</span>";
                var comment = "<span class='rev_comment'>"+ ris[i].commento + "<br><div class='rev_time'>" + ris[i].ora + "</div></span>";
                $("#reviews > ul").html($("#reviews > ul").html()+"<li style='margin-bottom:20px'>" + name + " " + comment + "</li>"); 
            }
            $("#new-comment").on('click', write_review);     
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }); 
}

function write_review(){
    var $newReview = $("<input class='new-input' type='text' id='insert' name='insert' placeholder='scrivi qui...'>"); 
    $("#reviews").append($newReview);   
    $("#new-comment").css("pointer-events", "none");        
    $newReview.on('keypress',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var comm = $(this);
            var datatime = new Date($.now());
            correctHour = printMysqlFormat(datatime);
            $.ajax({
                url:'reviews/reviews_query.php',
                data: {put:true, title: $("#right_title").text(), script: comm.val(), time: correctHour},     
                datatype:'json',
                success: function(json){
                    var output = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                    var newName = "<span class='rev_name'>"+ output + "</span>";
                    var newComment = "<span class='rev_comment'>"+ comm.val() + "<div class='rev_time'>" + correctHour + "</div></span>";
                    $("#reviews > ul").html($("#reviews > ul").html()+"<li style='margin-bottom:20px'>" + newName + " " + newComment + "</li>");
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
            $newReview.remove();       
            $("#new-comment").css("pointer-events", "auto"); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: *" I think that the problem is when I use the append function on the third line, but I don't know how to solve this."* Always have the input element in your markup (but hidden). Use jQuery to show and hide it. Alternatively: Remove the input element after adding the comment.

Comment: Can you try showing me some code for the second solution please? I've tried in the first way, but doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Just add `$('#insert').remove()` at the beginning of the `if` statement.

Comment: Still the same problem...

Comment: I see you are already removing the input element anyway. Something else might be going on then. Is the input element actually removed from the page? What's the context of the code you posted? Is it in another function?

Comment: Yes, the element, is actually removed, and I update my code

Comment: The reviews() function is called each time I open an article in my website

Comment: That might be the problem then. Every time `reviews` is called (and the content is loaded) you are adding a new click event handler to `#new-comment`, resulting in the handler being called multiple times when the element is clicked. You should bind the handler only once on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `$("#new-comment").on('click', write_review);`  with `$("#new-comment").one('click', write_review);`